# Regex not matching String

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm working on Date validation in Javascript using regex, and I'm consistently getting null return values when using an expression I verified using regex101. Any ideas on why this may not be working?

```js
var date = /(\w+)[\W]+(\w+)[\W]*(\w+)/;
var dateTest = "8-15-2003".match(date);
console.log("Date Test: " + dateTest);
```

Comment: Why such a complicated reg exp? Seems to be working fine in your snipplet.

Comment: You have a match here.

Comment: Have to break the date into 3 variables of almost any date format for a school project.

Comment: Please show where you're getting these null return values. That first case '8-15-2003' seems to be working just fine. And what is the output you are expecting?

Comment: Any date format is what? What are all the formats you have to match? What is an example one that fails?

Comment: Javascript's `Date` class would be a much better choice for this than regex.

Comment: @CAustin the project's requirements specify that I use regular expressions to pull the month, day, and year out of the inputted string, then use them to create a Date object

Comment: If that's the case, you'll have to be specific on the formats that the input could possibly come in. Please list examples of each, along with invalid input that you don't want to match.

Answer (score 1):

```
var date = /([\d]{1,2})-([\d]{1,2})-([\d]{4})/;
var dateTest = "8-15-2003".match(date);
console.log("Date Test: " + dateTest);
```

Comment: If you read the comments, apparently there are different formats OP is trying to match besides the one provided. What those are, we have no clue since no specifics were given.

Comment: yep. no specifics given, but the regex above could be simply modified:  `([\d]{1,2})[-/.]([\d]{1,2})[-/.]([\d]{4})`

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I need to be able to capture Alphabetic months as well, so simply grabbing digits isn't going to work.

Comment: @ColinSpratt well, you need to give us all date templates you want to match against in order to give us an opportunity to help you.

Comment: @ColinSpratt - Please edit your question, as this is a reasonable answer as asked.  If you need your regex to parse "any" date format, specify that, although I wouldn't expect many answers since that is a LARGE order.  I recommend specifying the formats you know you need to support.

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression:

var date = /^(0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-[12][0-9]{3}$/;

var dateTest = "08-15-2003".match(date);

console.log("Date Test: " + dateTest);